# Unable to extend ext4 with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

I know this might seem like a duplicate, but I've seen the other posts, and they're problems and different than mine.

I installed Ubuntu along side Windows 10, and now I want to take more 30Gb from the hard drive I installed Ubuntu on. However, I'm not being able to do it.

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSpGaeHlkoE) video on youtube, and my problem begins at minute 10:45. He is able to resize the extended partition while mine is locked. I also noticed that my ext4 root partition is inside the extended one. Here's what it looks like:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbsrC.png)

I'm super new to this, so I'm sorry if I'm doing something stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition locked because you run `gparted` from that partition, you need to run `gparted` from live usb.

Second problem is: you have free space before extended partition, not near partition you want to extend. Solution is move start of extended partition into free space, move partitions inside it to new begin of extended partition, and enlarge your ext4 partition when you have unallocated space near it. Back up your files first before moving/resizing partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your root partition (/dev/sda7) is *inside* an extended partition (/dev/sda2), and /dev/sda2 is full.

You will need to first extend the size of /dev/sda2 to use the empty space, and then you will probably need to move /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 so that the emtpy space is next to /dev/sda7.